# Best Approach of Using React Component in Angular 8+?

Tags: reactjs, angular, redux

I Have an angular Application build on 8+ now I have a requirement where I want to create react component and embed it in Angular Application.
How my Angular folder structure will be modified, is there any possible design pattern I have to follow while working both angular and react in one application?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a guru of the frontend, as I know it is possible.

1. Interact through Web Component spec
2. Apply Microfrontend patterns to mix Angular/React in the sample application
3. Ionic team created a project named [stencil](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil) which targets WebComponent development and conceptly it mixes the Angular and React good part in the same framework.

Comment: Thanks, Hantsy I will check with Microfrontend patterns.